# Integral in lemma 1.20 in Takesaki's book

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-algebras, bochner-spaces

Consider the following fragment from Takesaki's book "Theory of operator algebras II" chapter VI lemma 1.20:

[image]

How should the integral in (36) defined? I imagine it is some limit
$$\lim_{s\to \infty} \int_{0}^s + \lim_{t\to -\infty}\int_t^0$$
but then the question is how the integral
$$\int_a^b f(t)dt$$
is defined where $f:[a,b]\to A$ is a Banach-space valued function. Is this a Bochner integral? Or simply the usual Riemann integral? What ensures that such an integral exists?

Comment: The integral is absolutely convergent. The integrated function is continuous. Therefore it is the Bochner integral, in my opinion. The integral over bounded interval can be defined as the limit of partial sums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function $f:[a,b]\to A$ is continuous, then you can define the integral as a Riemann integral. If you look at how you prove that a Riemann integral  of a continuous function exists, you'll see that all you use regarding the codomain (that is $\mathbb R$ in the calculus case) is that it is a Banach space; that is, you take linear combinations and you use the absolute value for estimates, and completeness for the limit to exist. Everything works the same in a Banach space, you don't have to change the proofs at all. If you were to make the domain something else, say a Banach space, then things get more complicated and you need measure theory (which is where the Bochner integral fits in) because you need to somehow measure the size of your partition.

As for the improper integral, you can define it as you say. A Banach space is a place where Cauchy sequences are convergent, so if the sequence of integrals $\int_0^n f$ is Cauchy, then the limit will exist. And you always have the estimate
$$
\Big\|\int_a^bf(t)\,dt\Big\|\leq\int_a^b\|f(t)\|\,dt
$$
by the triangle inequality, which can be used to show that the sequence $\{\int_0^nf\}$ is Cauchy.

---

The Residue Theorem says that
$$\tag1
\oint_\gamma f(w)\,dw=2\pi i \sum_{z\in P_0} \operatorname{Res}(f,z)\,\operatorname{Ind}_\gamma(z).
$$
When $f$ is operator valued holomorphic/meromorphic, we consider a bounded linear functional $\varphi$ and then $\varphi\circ f$ is holomorphic/meromorphic. So
$$\tag2
\oint_\gamma (\varphi\circ f)(w)\,dw=2\pi i \sum_{z\in P_0} \operatorname{Res}(\varphi\circ f,z)\,\operatorname{Ind}_\gamma(z).
$$
Since $(\varphi\circ f)'=\varphi\circ f'$, the definition of residue works for $f$ and $\operatorname{Res}(\varphi\circ f,z)=\varphi(\operatorname{Res}(f,z))$. Hence
$$\tag3
\varphi\Bigg(\oint_\gamma f(w)\,dw\Bigg)=\varphi\Bigg(2\pi i \sum_{z\in P_0} \operatorname{Res}(f,z)\,\operatorname{Ind}_\gamma(z)\Bigg).
$$
And, as $\varphi$ was arbitrary, we get
$$\tag4
\oint_\gamma f(w)\,dw=2\pi i \sum_{z\in P_0} \operatorname{Res}(f,z)\,\operatorname{Ind}_\gamma(z).
$$
for operator-value meromorphic $f$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: In Takesaki's proof, the residue theorem for these Banach-space valued integrals are used. Is there a way to make sure to prove a version of this theorem without reproving everything in complex analysis? I will add a bounty to the question if you have time/interest to adress this :)

Comment: No need for a bounty. Usually, what works is applying a bounded linear functional to the whole thing. That is, if $f$ is operator-valued holomorphic, then $\varphi\circ f$ will be holomorphic. And if an equality occurs for all $\varphi$, then it holds at the operator level.

Comment: But why can we interchange functional and Riemann-integral? Don't we need Bochner integral instead then?

Comment: No. A boudned functional is continuous, and an integral is a limit of linear combinations; both things are preserved by the bounded functional. Bochner integral is a different game, it has to do when the *domain* is not one of the usual number fields.

Comment: I edited the idea in.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Much appreciated!